# cuDF: an alternative of Pandas Groupby + Shift?

Tags: pandas, rapids, cudf

I have a DF that I want to use Groupby + Shift. I can do this in pandas, but I cannot do it in cuDF because it is not implemented yet: see the issue [Issue #7183](https://github.com/rapidsai/cudf/issues/7183). The feature request was long ago, so it seems like they will not implement this in the near future. Is there any alternative way?

Comment: added an update as RAPIDS just added groupby.shift() to cudf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** RAPIDS just finished merging groupby.shift() into cudf.
Please try it out in the 21.06 nightlies!

**Previous Post:** This is currently planned to be implemented in 0.20.